How to correctly implement delay after enabling RCC peripheral clock?
I'm new to STM32 microcontrollers. I would like to know how to correctly implement 2-clock-cycle delay after enabling RCC peripheral clock.
Section 5.2.16 (page# 134) of https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0454-stm32g0x0-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

The enable bit has a synchronization mechanism to create a glitch-free clock for the peripheral. After the enable bit is set, there is a 2-clock-cycle delay before the clock be active, which the software must take into account.

I came across the below explanation and it appears to be correct.
https://github.com/lab11/stm32l0-base/blob/master/sdk/STM32Cube_FW_LO_V1.5.0/Drivers/STM32L0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l0xx_hal_rcc.c >
RCC Limitations ##### comments section.

This delay depends on the peripheral mapping.
If peripheral is mapped on AHB: the delay is 2 AHB clock cycles
after the clock enable bit is set on the hardware register
If peripheral is mapped on APB: the delay is 2 APB clock cycles
after the clock enable bit is set on the hardware register

I was looking at a couple of examples. In the first example, the RCC peripheral clock enable register is read back.
RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN_Pos);
  
// do two dummy reads after enabling the peripheral clock, as per the errata
volatile uint32_t dummy;
dummy = RCC->AHB1ENR;
dummy = RCC->AHB1ENR;

In the second example, the peripheral register is read back.
void clock_wait_bus_cycles(enum bus_type bus, uint32_t cycles)
{
    volatile uint32_t unused __attribute__((unused));
    if (bus == BUS_AHB) {
        while (cycles--)
            unused = STM32_DMA1_REGS->isr;
    } else { /* APB */
        while (cycles--)
            unused = STM32_USART_BRR(STM32_USART1_BASE);
    }
}

Which one is the correct approach?

what are you trying to do here?   the bus has a timing, and the peripheral has a timing and you can mess with the bus clock divisor down from the system clock.  the peripheral time is the peripheral time that logic takes some number of clocks, ideally 1, but not guaranteed, per register or task, etc.

counting cycles like this is on part with using a counter to blink.  your count value will vary simply due to the code you have written and what the compiler does with it, you can change code not even in this file and re-compile and it can dramatically change the counts you get per some unit time, and then how accurately you measure your time which is another place where folks get measurement errors it will be tough to get numbers that make any kind of sense.

your first statement then asks about how to make a delay.  other than an initial hello world blink the led which you can just do with a counter, no need to touch anything else.  and you hand tune that and expect it to change when you change code in the project.  If you want any kind of accuracy then you have to use a timer.   this is not a PIC nor other where you can count cycles by counting instructions.

so without knowing what you are asking "correctly implement delay" means us a timer, you do not have to use an interrupt, interrupts create their own problems.  so polled vs interrupt and other answers depend on the problem you are after.

Hi, I'm referring to section 5.2.16 (page# 134) of https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0454-stm32g0x0-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Here it cautions: The enable bit has a synchronization mechanism to create a glitch-free clock for the peripheral. After the enable bit is set, there is a 2-clock-cycle delay before the clock be active, which the software must take into account.

All I would like to know is how to take this 2-clock-cycle delay into account. I saw 2 different approaches to do this as mentioned in the post, not sure which approach is correct.

"I came across the below explanation..." citation required - where did you come across that.  Also STM32 covers a wide range of parts that often differ in subtle ways.  The STM34F4xx manual for example says nothing about it.  The the HAL only reads ENR once.

Hi, I've updated the post with the source where I came across that explanation.

Is reading RCC ENR register once the correct approach? Or reading the periphreal register?

STM32G0x0 for which you cited the reference manual has only on AHB bus and AHBENR not AHB1ENR so strictly the first is not correct for that specific part.

Yes, I couldn't find specific examples for STM32G0x0. I was trying to understand examples of other parts and then port it to STM32G0x0.

ST provide "examples" in the form of the HAL library - and for older STM32 parts the SPL.

There's never one single "best solution" in microcontrollers, as it's heavily dependent on context of several kinds (particular compiler and its command-line settings, mcu, AHB/APB settings, peripheral in question, memory from where code is executed...). Here some more snippets of information (I know it's already confusing but it is what it is) together with the methodology I use (basically, enable all clocks at one place at the beginning of program and then do something else useful before accessing the peripherals).

The first example is clearly for an STM32 part other then the STM32G0x0 which you are referencing, so in that sense it is not correct.  The STM32G0x0 which has one AHB so AHBENR not AHB1ENR, and the GPIOA clock is enabled via IOPENR not AHBENR in any case.  However the technique is legitimate, but needs to be specific to the part to be correct.
The function in the second method includes the function call overhead and a number of CPU cycles for the loop, so will be marginally longer, but that would be sweating the small stuff. It is perhaps unnecessarily complex.  The choice of peripheral to read in the second seems arbitrary.  You could equally read the appropriate RCC enable register as in the first example.  The requirement is only to read something that will have wait states dependent on the associated bus or peripheral, so that further instructions are not executed until the read is complete.
ST provide HAL and LL peripheral libraries which are probably good exemplars of recommended methods (or at least methods likely to be valid - and tested) - even if you choose not to use the libraries themselves.
The STM32G0x0 HAL does this for example:
#define __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()           do { \
                                                    __IO uint32_t tmpreg; \
                                                    SET_BIT(RCC->IOPENR, RCC_IOPENR_GPIOAEN); \
                                                    /* Delay after an RCC peripheral clock enabling */ \
                                                    tmpreg = READ_BIT(RCC->IOPENR, RCC_IOPENR_GPIOAEN); \
                                                    UNUSED(tmpreg); \
                                                  } while(0U)


It reads the individual enable bit that was just written, this guaranteeing to be the correct clock:
#define READ_BIT(REG, BIT)    ((REG) & (BIT))

The read will not complete until the clock is active, so a single read is sufficient I think.
The fact that the code in the first example will not work on the part you are using is perhaps an argument for using the ST provided HAL library - it avoids issues of using and porting code across multiple STM32 parts which vary considerable across series.

Related:ARM Bus architechure for reference.  This is a good answer, but it would help to say that the memory read instructions are done for a side effect.  That is the timing.  The 2nd issue is that the peripheral (on the bus) needs to have an active clock.  In the 2nd example the uart1 peripheral can not be disabled (for it to function).  Probably it is a boot device or something.  The first example seems more robust as you can not 'disable' the RCC (to my knowledge).

@artlessnoise. I made a bold assumption that it was understood that these were dummy reads for timing.  The point about those apparently arbitrary peripherals is important. I may update the answer.  The function would only work as intended if those were the first clocks to be enabled for each bus. It is seriously flawed and not just over complicated.  It is insufficiently generalised and will work in very narrow circumstances.  I suspect whoever wrote it never noticed because the overhead alone was sufficient delay - if the bus clock were >= Sysclk/4 say perhaps that might work by dumb luck.

more information... #define __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE ...   enables GPIOA peripheral clock via HAL to ensure GPIOA functionality by providing necessary clock signal.

@SheltonLiu. ??  Defining a macro does nothing in its own. Your suggestion simply creates an alias of an existing macro.  I am not sure what you gain, or what additional information is provided by your comment.

@Clifford you're right. defining a macro itself doesn't change but just explain this pattern is a common practice in stm32_hal_legacy.h.
